# css background image as screen

Tags: html, css

i have a `div` to which i want to assign a background image something like this:

the `div` has no fixed width, it is proportional to the body and let's say for some users has a 800 pixels width and for others 950 pixels

the background image is 1200 px wide to ensure that is wide enough for both users and the div acts something like a mask and show a narrower or a wider portion of the background image.

do you know if it is possible ?

Comment: `background-position:center;` should do it.

Comment: always put your script

Comment: If you're open to jQuery there is a plugin called [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) that does full screen images with practically no setup.

Comment: background-size:cover;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use background-size

```
.your_div { 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: i ran into a new problem...i want my background to be retina display compatible...so my image is something like 2000+ pixels wide and 1000+ pixels tall...and i get a very small portion of my image...and non-retina look... is there a way to do it retina compatible ? thanks